# Decrypting data using the RC2 algorithm

Tags: java, cryptography

I need to implement a java function that receives a password string and byte data from a user and decrypts it using the RC2 algorithm. Does anybody know how to do this in Java. If so, what classes should I use.

Thanks,
Vesely

Comment: What have you tried? What issues? ,... You can't expect us to write your code

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've done much research into this on your own. You're more likely to get an answer if you note what you've tried or found already.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, java does support RC2 out of the box, so you should be able to use [standard java crypto support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html).